# Multi Join using subquery

Tags: postgresql, join

Im trying to join multiple tables and add in a Subquery. There maybe an easier way if so please let me know.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(first_name), last_name, title, description, release_year,rating
FROM film_actor
INNER JOIN actor
ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
INNER JOIN film
ON film_actor.film_id = film.film_id; 
WHERE rental_rate > (SELECT AVG(rental_rate) FROM film)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) giving more details about your DB architecture otherwise it's hard to know how to optimize your query.

Comment: You have three tables: actor, film and film_actor. You want (first_name, last_name) from actor table, (title, description, release_year, rating) from film table; and you need film_actor relationship table to get them together. I don't see an easier way unless changing the design into one single film table with an actors json column.